# Make Model, Migration and Controller with one artisan command, but Controller needs to be in different directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

Is there a way to make Model, Migration and Controller with one Artisan command.
But the controller I would like to be in placed in different sub-directory, not in Artisan's default directory.
Thank you for help/suggestions.

Comment: What is the purpose for doing this all at once? As far as I can tell this would only require two to begin with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In two lines you could do:

```
//create model and migration
php artisan make:model ModelName -m

//create controller in subfolder
php artisan make:controller  subfolder/Controller
```